# How to convert PC or Laptop into ISP provider to Router?

Tags: testing, networking, automated-tests, modem

I need some information about the router. I want to test the Broadband Device for the frequency range, Bandwidth and control the Bandwidth also so I need to take the control of Broadband Device is an option for the above questions please let me know. thanks for the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not certainly clear that you can use your hotspot tethering service but still, the ISP will be the one who is providing you the broadband facility, so please edit your question and provide more information.

Comment: I have a router device I need to test the router device based on bandwidth and frequency change.so how to get the control of the router device

Comment: For this, you should visit the IP Address of the router which is generally given downside on the branding sticker of the router under 'DEFAULT SETTINGS'

Comment: On the IP Address, you will get complete freedon to change your router settings